# Как убрать фиксированный блок меню в шапке сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

на сайте https://testyotvety.ru/ (десктопной версии), есть прилипающее меню, при скроллинге оно залипает в шапке сайта.

Как правильно сделать, чтобы меню не залипало?
Пытался с помощью CSS, отключил position: fixed Но тогда сверху возникает пустое пространство. Скрин до отключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин после отключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие варианты есть, с помощью CSS можно сделать, чтобы и меню не залипало и пустого прямоугольника не было сверху?

Answer (score 0):

Самый легкий, быстрый способ, ничего больше не меняя

```
.headhesive {
    ...
    z-index: 0;
    ...
}
```

Вместо `z-index: 999;`